# Remove unwanted rows based on nth character

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report (image below) and I just want the unique Product Code and remove all the unwanted rows that doesn't have "*" on the 5th place from left, but at the same time I want to keep row 18 as the header. How do I fix that? Thanks in advance.

[image]

I have the code:

```
Sub Remove_Unwanted_Cells()
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    'Dim c As Range

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        .Select
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Firstrow = 2
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For Lrow = lastRow To Firstrow Step -1
            With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
                For Each Cell In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row)
                If Mid(Cell, 5, 1) <> "*" Then Cell.EntireRow.Delete
                Next Cell
            End With
         Next Lrow
    End With


    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: If you change to ~For Lrow = lastRow To 19 Step -1~ would it workout?

Comment: Hi skkakkar, thanks but it's not working :(

Comment: It removes the word if the '*' is not at 5th position correctly but shifts the corrected rows upwards one by one while looping and takes to the top row. Look for solution of this shifting upwards in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pl change corresponding lines to :

```
       For Each Cell In Range("A19:A" & lastRow)
            If Mid(Cell, 5, 1) <> "*" Then Cell.EntireRow.Delete
```

**EDIT**
Regarding your point to delete rows `1 to 17` also, please insert a line

```
  Rows("1:17").Delete
```

in your code as shown below.

```
 End With
Rows("1:17").Delete

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks, its working perfectly but I also wanted to remove those unwanted cells from row 1 to 17

Comment: @phelia91 I shall reply to you a little later regarding removing row 1 to 17. Happy that I could catch the point.

Comment: @phelia91 I am not too sure you want to remove entire rows in the range above Headers or you want to clear contents of selected range. In case you want to remove the entire rows above Headers, simple addition of one line will serve your purpose.

Comment: I preferred to work on your code as it will clarify the shortcomings and is a good building block of experience for both of us. I have deep respect and regards for @Gary's Student and you have rightly chosen his answer as accepted as it is better.

Comment: I wish I can choose answers from both of you as accepted, really! Btw, @Gary's Student thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Remove_Unwanted_Cells()
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

    With Application
         CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Firstrow = 2
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Lrow = lastRow To Firstrow Step -1
            If Mid(Cells(Lrow, 1), 5, 1) <> "*" Then Cells(Lrow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
     Next Lrow


    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Gary's Student, thanks its working perfectly but it took row 1 as the header instead of row 18, how do I fix that?

Comment: @phelia91  If you change  `Firstrow = 2` into  `Firstrow = 19` the code will ignore rows **1** through **18**

Comment: Thank you very much for helping!